# Error Calling Python code from .Net Core 6 web api

Tags: c#-6.0, python.net

I am using PythonNet 3.0.1 in my .Net Core 6C# project.
Need is to call a .py file and process a csv and read the results back in C#.
Have installed Python 3.11.4 on my machine as well as pandas library.

Now when I call the Api Code, it gives an error whenever I try to call the Api method more than once.

I have added a finally block with the following statement:
PythonEngine.Shutdown()

The exception logged on console is:

System.NotSupportedException: BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.

at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)

at Python.Runtime.RuntimeData.Stash()

at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Shutdown()

at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Shutdown()

How do I fix this error and ensure that the Api can be called more than once?

here is the Code I have in the C# class:

```
string fileLoc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
         try
        {
            Runtime.PythonDLL = "python311.dll";
            // Initialize the Python engine
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic module = Py.Import("PythonSampleIronPython");
                dynamic result = module.calculator.xl2determination(fileLoc);
            }
            return new Audit();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Unable to evaluate model", err);
            throw new Exception("Unable to evaluate model", err);
        }
        finally{
            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        }
```

I did not find much help using Pythonnet. So appreciate any help from people using Pythonnet with C#

Here is the Python Code saved in file "PythonSampleIronPython.py".

class calculator:
def add(x, y):
return x + y
def increment(x):
x += 1
return x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by intializing the `PythonEngine` on startup in `Program.cs`:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", "path to python dll");
PythonEngine.PythonHome = "Path to Python installation";
PythonEngine.Initialize();
PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
```

Then you can test it by using something like this:

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
    PythonEngine.Exec("print('Hello from Python')")
}
```

This solution doesn't require you to call `PrintEngine.Shutdown()` since it's running for the lifecycle of the application.

Using the github solution provided in the other answer:

I created a new class `NoopFormatter` that inherits from `IFormatter`:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace YourNameSpace;

public class NoopFormatter : IFormatter
{
    public object Deserialize(Stream s) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Serialize(Stream s, object o) { }

    public SerializationBinder Binder { get; set; }
    public StreamingContext Context { get; set; }
    public ISurrogateSelector SurrogateSelector { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my class where I'm using the `Python.Runtime` I added this line before `PythonEngine.Initialize()`

```
Python.Runtime.RuntimeData.FormatterType = typeof(NoopFormatter);
```

This allowed `PrintEngine.ShutDown()` to execute without throwing the BinaryFormatter serialization exception.

**Note**: Depending on the use of threading in your application you may need to include `PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads()` after you call `PythonEngine.Initialize();` This fixed the issue of it locking up on `using (Py.GIL())` when hitting the code a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Stepping through the code, a BinaryFormatter is created during Stash() on shutdown, even if I wasn't handling or returning binary data. This no-op formatter workaround resolved the issue for me: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/2008#issuecomment-1441315835

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).